How to connect two screens through a HP dock G5 with my Lenovo ideapad 330S-15ARR
I have a Lenovo ideapad 330S-15ARR on Ubuntu 24.04.1 (buying this pc to use linux on it was a bad decision)
I want to connect my HP USB-C Dock G5 in order to used the rest of my setup with this laptop. This dock work for my mouse and keyboard : Image of the lsusb showing the dock, the keyboard and mouse.
But I cannot use my two screens. They are not in the setting, I cannot interact with them. The xrandr display what I think are the display port of the dock, since my computer don't have display port, but I cannot used them.
This is the result of the xrandr command.
I have try a lot of things, but none work. I have displaylink driver and they are working.
$XDG_SESSION_TYPE is X11. DisplayLink Driver Service is loaded and running. All should be fine, but it like I have forgot a driver or something...
This computer had a RADEON vega graphics, it's a full AMD computer.
Do you have any ideas on how I can make this computer working with my two screens through my dock G5 ?
